# Postgres migrate uuid column type with default value doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

My migration is

```
class AddUuidToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :uuid, :uuid, null: false, default: 'uuid_generate_v4()'
    add_index :users, :uuid
  end
end
```

The schema is changed with:

```
t.uuid     "uuid",                               default: "uuid_generate_v4()"
```

As you see, we the `null: false` is not added, not sure why?

But when I try with a common column type for instance `string` it works well.

Is there any limitation for `:uuid` column type that we can't use `null: false`?

Comment: There is no limitation on PostgreSQL side for this type. I just set `NOT NULL` with no issues. You could work around this problem by trying to use `change_column_null`, tho I suppose it does not answer you question.

Answer (score 3):

Rails 4.2 totally ignore `null` option for uuid columns with a default value. You may check a column object for your model:

```
> User.columns[2] # number of uuid column
=> #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLColumn:0x007fe6fee53f20 ...
@sql_type="uuid", @null=true, @default=nil, @default_function="uuid_generate_v4()">
```

But migration options was the same as in your example:

```
add_column :users, :uuid, :uuid, null: false, default: 'uuid_generate_v4()'
```

Rails 5.0 had fixed this bug. Column object keeps `null` option for the same migration:

```
> User.columns[2]
=> #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLColumn:0x007fa6c3722650 ...
@sql_type="uuid", @type=:uuid, @null=false, @default=nil, @default_function="uuid_generate_v4()", @collation=nil, @comment=nil>
```

And `schema.rb` also contains `null: false`:

```
t.uuid   "uuid", default: -> { "uuid_generate_v4()" }, null: false
```